# What is the English equivalent to the Portuguese word "Crônica"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, translation

According to the [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chronicle?fallbackFrom=english-portuguese), a *"chronicle"* is a written record of historical events or part of the name of a newspaper.

In Portuguese, *"crônica"* can also be used as a written record of historical events but it's more used to define works of a hybrid journalistic genre in which the author kinda of writes an opinion article about some actual theme (normally critic) in the form of a fictional very short story.

- I can use *"article"* to translate *"crônica"*, but it would be too wide.
- *"Chronicle"* is clearly unfit.

So, my question is:

- *"Is there any word in English that clearly translates the concept of an opinion article, criticizing some actual theme, written in the form of a fictional very short story"*?

@edited: Btw, a "crônica", in the Brazilian perspective, can or cannot be political. The key point is it must criticize society or somebody in some way. I found a very small example of a "crônica" with the original in Portuguese and an English translation. I added the link below. Maybe this helps:

- [Advantage of Being Dumb](http://lillibarroso.blogspot.pt/2010/09/das-vantagens-de-ser-bobo-clarice.html)

Comment: I'm not sure we have exactly the same thing in the UK, but 'Political Sketch Writing' might be close in spirit? if you think that is related enough I'll try and write a proper answer on those lines. Is it possible for you to find any links to English translations of examples of  "crônica"?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliamentary_sketch_writing https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2016/nov/14/mays-banquet-speech-out-blinged-by-farages-trump-tower-snaps

Comment: I edit my question to answer your comment. The "Political Sketch Writing" must political, the "crônica" just criticizes society in any way the author wants. I added a link to a "crônica" in my answer.

Comment: I really want to answer "blog"... but it's not at all the right word.

Comment: When you are writing about a real situation, but using the methods of fiction, you're making an *allegory*.  But allegory doesn't necessarily mean social critique or political critique.

Comment: It sounds like a [fictionalised account](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fictionalised) (do a text search in the linked entry for "fictionalised account" to find some examples), but the term doesn't really refer to *opinion articles*.

Comment: Is the story necessarily satirical, or can it just directly denounce its subject?

Comment: @Spagirl Sounds like a political sketch, but without the politics. Consider "Sketch" as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the definition in Wikipedia

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%B4nica_(g%C3%AAnero)

a "crônica" introduces, I'm guessing by the root of the word, a sense of periodicity. So I would probably translate it to *Column*. More specifically, a *newspaper column*, which often includes the author's opinions and can, but does not have to be political.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_(periodical)

> A column is a recurring piece or article in a newspaper, magazine or other publication, where a writer expresses his/her own opinion in few columns allotted to him by the newspaper organisation. Columns are written by columnists.
>
> What differentiates a column from other forms of journalism is that is a regular feature in a publication – written by the same writer or reporter and usually on the same subject area or theme each time – and that it typically, but not universally, contains the author's opinion or point of view.

Comment: It does imply periodicity, in the sense that a _crónica_ is always there in every issue, on the same place and with the same layout (usually at the start of the issue). It differs from columns, though, in that the writer(s) of a _crónica_ are usually not regulars. You don't have a _crónica_ in a newspaper the way you have a column; anyone can submit a _crónica_ and the paper then chooses somewhat arbitrarily whether to bring it or not. It's essentially just a **feature**, though that term is a bit too broad to accurately describe a _crónica_ by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [treatise](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/treatise) would work for you

> A systematic, usually extensive written discourse on a subject. [TFD]

or maybe [think piece](http://a%20piece%20of%20writing%20meant%20to%20be%20thought-provoking%20and%20speculative%20that%20consists%20chiefly%20of%20background%20material%20and%20personal%20opinion%20and%20analysis)

> a piece of writing meant to be thought-provoking and speculative that consists chiefly of background material and personal opinion and analysis [MWD]

Although both words refer mostly to an indiviudal article rather than a complete body of work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a single word in English that is an exact fit. [Social satire](http://literarydevices.net/satire/) might be the closest to what you describe, in terms of style and intent, but not necessarily length. *"...a technique employed by writers to expose and criticize foolishness and corruption of an individual or a society by using humor, irony, exaggeration or ridicule. It intends to improve humanity by criticizing its follies and foibles. A writer in a satire uses fictional characters, which stand for real people, to expose and condemn their corruption."*